# How to run single test case in multiple instances of browser parallelly without selenium grid

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am setting up a framework and want to run a single test method(of hitting url & then do some operations), in multiple browser instances parallel
(e.g: hitting a url by opening ~5 chrome browser instances at same time)

I have been able run different test methods parallel before but i want to run single test case multiple times at once(parallel)

GoogleTest.java

```
@Test(invocationCount=2)
public void hitUrl() throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = getDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
}
```

TestNG.xml

```
<suite thread-count="2" verbose="2" name="Gmail Suite"
    annotations="JDK" parallel="methods">

    <test name="Google_Test">
        <classes>
            <class name="big.GoogleTest">
                <methods>
                    <include name="hitUrl" />
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
```

I am expecting to open two browser instances of chrome at once but they are running in single browser instance one after another.

Answer (score 0):

With `@Test(invocationCount= int Values)` it will run your code in same browser for specified values.

you could create a  node for each time you want to run the class, then parallelize by `test`. You'd also want to move your parallelization attributes to the `<suite>` node. For example:

### TestNG.xml

```
<suite name="ParallelTestingGoogle" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="5">
    <test name="1st">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.className"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="2nd">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.className" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="3rd">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.className" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="4th">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.className" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="5th">
        <classes>
            <class name="packageName.className" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

[image]

### JAVA :

```
public class TC1 {
    WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    public void testCaseOne() {
        // Printing Id of the thread on using which test method got executed
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "your ChromeDriver path");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    }
}
```